# Cython: Returning C buffer memoryview to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, buffer, cython

I have following Cython code with one C buffer defined (`c_buffer`):

```
ctypedef struct my_struct_t:
    float x
    float y

cdef class CMyClass:
    cdef my_struct_t c_buffer[1000]

    def get_array(self):
        return <my_struct_t[:1000]>&self.c_buffer[0]

    def get_memoryview(self):
        return memoryview(<my_struct_t[:1000]>&self.c_buffer[0])
```

I'm using this class to store elements that eventually go to OpenGL VBO buffer. What I'm trying to do is avoid unnecessary copies of memory.

When I call `get_array()` I get result of type

```
<c_wrappers.array object at 0x7fffce17d650>
```

with `get_memoryview()` the result is:

```
<memory at 0x7fffd242e648>
```

1. What's the difference between them (in functionality/speed)? I'm reading official document in about [Typed Memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html), but it focuses mainly on numpy. Am I returning the memoryviews here correctly?
2. Now the buffer is fixed (max 1000 elements). Does in Cython exist dynamic array that I could use and it automatically handles memory for me (for adding/removing elements at runtime) and having continuous memory layout (that I could eventually supply to OpenGL VBO)? Or should I use `from libcpp.vector cimport vector`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a quite complicated question! There are some aspects that need to be considered.

**The speed:**

Let's start with a simple `int`-buffer (I've skipped the unnecessary `&c_buffer[0]`-business):

```
%%cython
cdef class CMyClass:
    cdef int c_buffer[1000]

    def get_array(self):
        return <int[:1000]>self.c_buffer

    def get_memoryview(self):
        return memoryview(<int[:1000]>self.c_buffer)
```

"Typed memory view" is somewhat opaque in Cython, there are some classes which are very similar and are returned from the function depending on the signature of the function:

- [array](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/902be3fc9e49f64bb3682e849d56d54f70ae8d08/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L104)
- [memoryview](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/902be3fc9e49f64bb3682e849d56d54f70ae8d08/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L329)
- [memoryviewslice](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/902be3fc9e49f64bb3682e849d56d54f70ae8d08/Cython/Utility/MemoryView.pyx#L960)
- There is also a helper struct [__Pyx_memviewslice](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/fd85d226118aac2ce315becb020d3509f7417bfc/Cython/Compiler/PyrexTypes.py#L4196), which is not returned by used in function.

However, none of these above is the memoryview you are returning in your second-function: it returns [Python's memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview).

Quite confusing! Personally, I keep it simple and trust Cython to return the best suitable class - to me it just a buffer.

When we measure the speed, the first version will be faster, because wrapping array_obj into a Python's memoryview just adds complexity:

```
>>>c=CMyClass()
>>>%timeit c.get_array()
377 ns ± 1.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>>%timeit c.get_memoryview()
561 ns ± 2.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

**The lifetime:**

The memory from `c_buffer` isn't copied:

```
>>>c=CMyClass()
>>>c.get_array()[0]=42
>>>print(c.get_memoryview()[0])
```

Which sounds like a Good Thing, but isn't!  The problem: `c_buffer` isn't a Python-object and when it goes out of scope, the data-pointer of the memory-view becomes dangling:

```
>>c=CMyClass()
>>>c.get_array()[0]=42
>>>c=c.get_array()   # old c-object is now destroyed
>>>print(c[0])       # anything can happen!
-304120624
```

I got lucky, the python didn't crash but it could, because after binding `c` to the memoryview, the underlying object is destroyed and the memory freed.

Using `std::vector` will not help you there. What you need is a real Python-object with reference counting! For example we could use Cython's array for that:

```
%%cython 

from cython.view cimport array as cvarray
cdef class CMyClass:
    cdef int[:] c_buffer

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_buffer = cvarray(shape=(1000,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="i")

    def  get_array(self):
        cdef int[:] res=self.c_buffer # nobody needs to know which class we use
        return res
```

Now the code from above is safe:

```
>>c=CMyClass()
>>>c.get_array()[0]=42
>>>c=c.get_array()   # old c-object is now destroyed
>>>print(c[0])       # but the underlying memory is still alive
42
```

---

**Custom structs:**

But what about customs structs, as in your example above? The probably easiest way is to use numpy:

```
%%cython -a
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

#define a type for memory view
ctypedef packed struct my_struct_t:
    np.float32_t x
    np.float32_t y

#define a type for numpy-array (is a python-object)
my_struct = np.dtype([
    ('x', np.float32, 1), 
    ('y', np.float32, 1),  
])

cdef class CMyClass:
    cdef object c_buffer

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.c_buffer = np.empty(1000,dtype=my_struct)

    def  get_array(self):
        cdef my_struct_t[:] res=self.c_buffer
        return res
```

Which works as advertised:

```
>>>c=CMyClass()
>>>c.get_array()[0]={'x':42,'y':42}
>>>c=c.get_array()   # old c-object is now destroyed
>>>print(c[0])       # but this is still ok
{'x': 42.0, 'y': 42.0}
```

Two more remarks:

- using numpy is slower - `get_array()` is three times slower than the original `get_array()` version
- using `my_struct_t c_buffer` would not really help you there (beside being dangerous), because there would be no rule how to translate the data from c-struct to an python object, but this check happens at run time, when the elements of the array are acccessed.

Comment: Thanks for exhausting answer! Just few remarks: so "typed memory view" is just a concept and I need to find proper function(malloc, cvarray etc..) to set it? In your example you set cvarray to 1000, what if i want add more elements at runtine? Should I reallocate?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I think of "typed memory views" as an abstraction. I don't see much  value in known which classes/combination of classes makes it work.

Comment: @AndrejKesely you could use `array.array`, which can grow dynamically: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html. However, if there are memory views around, they lock the underlying buffer, so it cannot be changed.

Comment: I see, it's complicated...I want to grab memoryview only when I'm ready to draw the buffer, so that shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for clarifying me the typed memory view.